# how do i post selected options in php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu, onchange

I'm trying to get the text of the selected value in HTML `select` box.
I've tried using `onchange` event but I realized it is messing up JavaScript calculations. Is there another way to get text of the selected value without interfering with the auto-calculation function?

```
<select style="width: 300px;" name="typeofdocument" class="form-control" onchange="getText(this)" onchange="javascript:doOrderFormCalculation();" onclick="javascript:doOrderFormCalculation();" id="typeofdocument">                    
    <option value="1" >Essay</option>
    <option value="2" >Term Paper</option>
    <option value="3" >Research Paper</option>
    <option value="4" >Coursework</option>
    <option value="5" >Book Report</option>
    <option value="6" >Book Review</option>
    <option value="7" >Movie Review</option>
    <option value="8" >Dissertation</option>
```

Comment: _"but I realized it is messing up JavaScript calculations"_ - Messing up what calculations how? You can also only have one `onchange` attribute per element. If you need to call multiple functions, it should be in the same attribute: `onchange="foo(); bar()"`

Answer (score 0):

use this code for JQuery

```
$('#typeofdocument').change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
    javascript:doOrderFormCalculation();
});
```

and this for native JS

```
const selectElement = document.getElementById('typeofdocument');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    javascript:doOrderFormCalculation();
});
```

and remove `onchange`, `onclick`

Comment: Since the OP hasn't mentioned jQuery, it would probably be better to write an answer using vanilla JS.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Added both options for both cases.